# Условие в запросе

Tags: mysql

Нужно составить такое условие:

выбрать id из таблицы, где url like $a и где этот же url не like $b

попытка такая:

```
SELECT id FROM main WHERE url LIKE '$a%' AND url NOT LIKE '$b%'
```

этот запрос не корректно работает. = вместо like не предлагать

Comment: Приведите запрос без переменных, с подставленными данными.

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, ожидаемое поведение и то, которое вы получаете (т.е. опишите то, в чём состоит некорректность)

Comment: Приведите пример данных и опишите в чем заключается некорректность с Вашей точки зрения. Как по мне, так запрос полностью правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/055a8/3
Вот ваш пример, что значит некорректно работает?

Comment: с мой стороны косяк, $a и $b местами поменял

Answer (score 2):

Запрос составлен верно; единственное что смущает - это кавычки. Если это PHP (вроде похоже), то кавычки нужны двойные: `"`, иначе переменные не интерполируются, т.е. так и останутся `$a%`.

```
$a = 'world';
print "Hello $a!"; // Hello world!
print 'Hello $a!'; // Hello $a!
```

Answer (score 2):

Кавычки можно внутри двойных кавычек писать, чтобы не прибегать к экранированию.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM main WHERE url LIKE '$a%' AND url NOT LIKE '$b%'";
```

А вообще, это плохой подход. Возможна sql-инъекция. Нужно так

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql;dbname=test;", 'admin', 'admin');
$q = $conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM main WHERE url LIKE :a AND url NOT LIKE :b');
$q->bindParam(':a', "$a%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':b', "$b%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: зачем экранировать одинарные кавычки внутри двойных?

Comment: Rufex, точно. Глупость написал. Спасибо, поправил.